# Сделать span неактивным

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такая конструкция на сайте:

```
<a href="profile-v-1.php" class="profile__nav-item">
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/icons/profile__ver.png">
                                <img src="img/icons/profile__ver--green.png">
                            </div>
                            <span>Verification</span>
                        </a>
```

Как сделать span неактивным(чтоб по нему вообще нельзя было нажать), если допустим значение поля в БД равно 1.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо ссылки передать #

```
<a href="<? if($db['active'] == 1) echo "#"; else echo "profile-v-1.php"; ?>" class="profile__nav-item">
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/icons/profile__ver.png">
                                <img src="img/icons/profile__ver--green.png">
                            </div>
                            <span>Verification</span>
                        </a>
```