# Отключить клик по span

Tags: php

Суть в том, что мне нужно сделать спан неактивным(некликабельным) когда значение переменной $checkval == 1, но моя конструкция работает через раз.

```
<?php
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Verification` WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
    $check_row = $check->fetch_assoc();
    $checkval = $check_row["Complete"];
echo'<a href="profile-v-1.php" class="profile__nav-item">';
echo'                           <div>';

echo'                       <img src="img/icons/profile__ver.png">';
echo'                       <img src="img/icons/profile__ver--green.png">';
echo'                           </div>';
if ($checkval == 0) 
echo'<span>Verification</span>';
else
echo' <span onclick="return false;">Verification</span>';

echo'                       </a>';


?>
```

Comment: В чем заключается "кликабельность" `span`-а?

Comment: @Igor в том что на него навешено событие `onclick`

Comment: Но так как у автора все это обернуто в `a` то это вообще всегда кликабельно. __Рекомендуется__ вынести `span` из `a` чтобы не ловить баги.

Comment: вообще по клику на спан юзера переносит на profile-v-1.php

Comment: Нет, "юзера переносит" по клику на анкeр.

Comment: Логику вообще стоит переписать. Если юзер верифицирован - не надо выводить никаких ссылок.

Comment: И вам уже в другой задаче пояснили что делать - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899971/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-span-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc Зачем вы какие-то новые костыли прикручиваете?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
    <?php
    $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Verification` WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
    $check_row = $check->fetch_assoc();
    $checkval = $check_row["Complete"];

    if ($checkval == 0) {
      echo '<a href="profile-v-1.php" class="profile__nav-item">
        <div>
          <img src="img/icons/profile__ver.png">
          <img src="img/icons/profile__ver--green.png">
        </div>
      </a>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<span>Verification</span>';
    }
```